# Select left join in Yii2 is failed

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii2, left-join

When I following [this tutorial](http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/select-query-joins/#innerJoinWith) and I tried for part the left join is failed. I don't know why, how can I fix it?

This code in controller:

```html
public function actionGetSka($kodeSka)
    {
        $query = new Query;
        $query->select(['ska.no_ska','ska.tgl_ska','ska.kode_anak_asuh','anak_asuh.kode_calon','calon.nama_calon','ska.kode_calon_keluarga_asuh','calon_keluarga_asuh.nama','calon_keluarga_asuh.jenis_kelamin','calon_keluarga_asuh.pekerjaan','calon_keluarga_asuh.alamat'])  
              ->from('ska')
              ->join('LEFT JOIN', 'anak_asuh',
                'anak_asuh'.'kode_anak_asuh' = 'ska'.'kode_anak_asuh')      
              ->join('LEFT JOIN', 'calon_keluarga_asuh', 
                'calon_keluarga_asuh'.'kode_calon_keluarga_asuh' = 'ska'.'kode_calon_keluarga_asuh')
              ->join('LEFT JOIN', 'calon', 
                'calon'.'kode_calon' = 'anak_asuh'.'kode_calon')
              ->limit(2); 
        $command = $query->createCommand();
        $data = $command->queryAll();
        echo Json::encode($kodeSka);
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

wrong quote around table name in join

you should use `'anak_asuh.kode_anak_asuh' = 'ska.kode_anak_asuh'` instead of

`'anak_asuh'.'kode_anak_asuh' = 'ska'.'kode_anak_asuh'`

```
  public function actionGetSka($kodeSka)
      {
          $query = new Query;
          $query->select(['ska.no_ska'
            ,'ska.tgl_ska'
            ,'ska.kode_anak_asuh'
            ,'anak_asuh.kode_calon'
            ,'calon.nama_calon'
            ,'ska.kode_calon_keluarga_asuh'
            ,'calon_keluarga_asuh.nama'
            ,'calon_keluarga_asuh.jenis_kelamin'
            ,'calon_keluarga_asuh.pekerjaan'
            ,'calon_keluarga_asuh.alamat'])  
                ->from('ska')
                ->join('LEFT JOIN', 'anak_asuh', 'anak_asuh.kode_anak_asuh' = 'ska.kode_anak_asuh')      
                ->join('LEFT JOIN', 'calon_keluarga_asuh', 'calon_keluarga_asuh.kode_calon_keluarga_asuh' = 'ska.kode_calon_keluarga_asuh')
                ->join('LEFT JOIN', 'calon', 'calon.kode_calon' = 'anak_asuh.kode_calon')
                ->limit(2); 
          $command = $query->createCommand();
          $data = $command->queryAll();
          echo Json::encode($kodeSka);
      }
```

Comment: is strange  .. i have posted the right solution before the others and with proper explanation of the error cause and you you mark as accepted  the others without any explanation and pratically the code copied for  mine .. if mine is wronh you could at least tell me ..

Comment: Bro your and my answer is different, and it is upto questioner to whom answer he accept, Still you down voted me for this and other answer :)

Comment: i don't see appreciable  difference .in the answer ... a part the look ..

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
public function actionGetSka($kodeSka)
    {
        $query = new Query;
        $query->select(['ska.no_ska','ska.tgl_ska','ska.kode_anak_asuh','anak_asuh.kode_calon','calon.nama_calon','ska.kode_calon_keluarga_asuh','calon_keluarga_asuh.nama','calon_keluarga_asuh.jenis_kelamin','calon_keluarga_asuh.pekerjaan','calon_keluarga_asuh.alamat'])  
              ->from('ska')
              ->leftJoin('anak_asuh','anak_asuh.kode_anak_asuh = ska.kode_anak_asuh')
              ->leftJoin('calon_keluarga_asuh','calon_keluarga_asuh.kode_calon_keluarga_asuh = ska.kode_calon_keluarga_asuh')
              ->leftJoin('calon','calon.kode_calon = anak_asuh.kode_calon')
              ->limit(2); 
        $command = $query->createCommand();
        $data = $command->queryAll();
        echo Json::encode($kodeSka);
    }
```